# Error 1216: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am using mysql version 8.0.30.
I have a table with 40+ columns out of that 20+ columns have foreign key constraints. Very frequently we get this issue

`"Error 1216: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"`.

I understand what the error means and how to figure out the cause and resolve it. But, with so many foreign key constraints it is time consuming.

Is there a way to figure out which foreign key constraint is failing? I am not in a position to change table structure or ignore the foreign key constraints due to business reasons. Is there a command or setting in mysql to get more detailed error information?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo of a table with two foreign keys, and I violate one of them. But which one?

```
mysql> create table t1 ( id int primary key);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> create table t2 (id int primary key);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> create table t3 (id int primary key, f1 int, f2 int,
 foreign key (f1) references t1(id), 
 foreign key (f2) references t2(id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into t1 values (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into t3 values (1, 1, 2);
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: 
 a foreign key constraint fails 
 (`test`.`t3`, CONSTRAINT `t3_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`f2`) REFERENCES `t2` (`id`))
```

The error tells you which one was violated.

If that's not clear, run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G` in a mysql client (the `\G` is so you don't get a huge box around the result). The output is kind of long, but one part of it will show the details of the most recent foreign key error:

```
...
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2022-12-09 10:11:12 0x175a53000 Transaction:
TRANSACTION 7521, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 21, OS thread handle 6268727296, query id 694 localhost root update
insert into t3 values (1, 1, 2)
Foreign key constraint fails for table `test`.`t3`:
,
  CONSTRAINT `t3_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`f2`) REFERENCES `t2` (`id`)
Trying to add in child table, in index f2 tuple:
DATA TUPLE: 2 fields;
 0: len 4; hex 80000002; asc     ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;

But in parent table `test`.`t2`, in index PRIMARY,
the closest match we can find is record:
PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 696e66696d756d00; asc infimum ;;
...
```

Note this shows the latest foreign key error *in any session*, so if the errors are occurring frequently, you'll have to be quick to get the details of one before it is replaced by the next one. See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-errors

Comment: Thanks for quickly creating a succinct example. I tried the exact same use case you provided on my mysql instance. It gives me "ERROR 1216 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails". It does not give me the second half you have mentioned above mentioning the actual foreign key. Is there a special DB setting required? Do I need to be a "admin" user to get that information? I cannot get admin privileges.

Comment: There's no configuration or privilege needed. I tested in the mysql client and using a Python script, and both reported the full error details. I'm thinking your client is truncating the error somehow.

Comment: I tested it on  % mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.30 for macos12.4 on arm64 (Homebrew) if that works, I was planning to find out how to do that in my golang client

Comment: Mine is 8.0.31 but I don't see anything in the release notes to suggest the behavior changed.